# Sparql Filter : get all details of a match

Tags: sparql

I have following sparql query:

```
PREFIX spec: <http://rdfs.org/sioc/spec/> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX constraint: <http://purl.org/vocab/constraint/constraint#>

SELECT  
(sample(?FName) as ?fName)
(sample(?Midname) as ?midname) 
(sample(?User) as ?user)  

(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?userRole;  separator='; ') AS ?UserRole)
WHERE {
    GRAPH <http://example.com/> 
    {
        ?User spec:email ?Email .   
        ?User foaf:firstName ?FirstName .
        ?User foaf:surname ?Midname .
        OPTIONAL
        {
            ?User constraint:containsConstraint ?constraint .               
            ?constraint constraint:constrains ?userRoleUri .
            ?userRoleUri spec:name ?userRole.
        }
FILTER (str(?userRoleUri) IN("http://example.com/roles/admin", "http://example.com/roles/moderator"))

    }
} GROUP BY ?FName  ORDER BY ASC(?FName)
```

What this query does is it returns the matching user.
So, if a user "A" has 3 roles listed : editor, admin and moderator, it displays only two roles for user. 
like :

```
A - Mid - a@abc.om - admin;moderator
```

What i wanted to do from query is :
since user A matches any of the given filter conditions, all it's roles should be listed. Is there a way to improve this query? I have tried using sub select and regex in filters as well, but :(

Thanks in advance 
Sparqler

Comment: Duplicated with some answers at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/20016/sparql-filter-get-all-details-of-a-match

Comment: thnx, I posed the question on sematicweb, but I was not sure that semantic web = stackoverflow...

Comment: It does not, they are run by separate people but it's always useful to point people between the duplicates so that future users can find all available answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proposed solution on answers.Sematicweb.com solves to problem to a great extent. It's exactly what I need, but, very much possible.

**Answer to this : **
[http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/20016/sparql-filter-get-all-details-of-a-match](https://web.archive.org/web/20140308050637/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/20016/sparql-filter-get-all-details-of-a-match)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can't see the 'editor' role in your FILTER clause. 
Re. displaying all related roles, why not simply utilising the following SELECT clause:

```
SELECT ?FName ?Midname ?userRole
```

?

Comment: I can't modify the select clause, because, I need to display all roles using ; as separator

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have the list of role for a user only if he is admin or moderator.

In this case, I would add a second userRoleUri.

something like this:

```
?User constraint:containsConstraint ?constraint .               
?constraint constraint:constrains ?userRoleUri .
?constraint constraint:constrains ?userRoleUri2 .
?userRoleUri2 spec:name ?userRole.
```

so this filter your user on the ?userRoleUri but then list all the ?userRole via ?userRoleUri2

I think That should work.